# HttpWebRequest usage in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, http, web, websocket

`System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse` raises an error

> "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a send"

in my program.

The request creates a parameter which can be of varying length and uses oAuth.  It works when the parameter string length is less than 12250 characters long, but fails with the above error if it gets longer.

Feels like it's the size of the message that is the problem, needless to say!

In all machine.config files, I have:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="32768" />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

set KeepAlive to false,  `webRequest.KeepAlive = false;`

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527407/how-do-i-prevent-my-net-soap-client-from-including-connection-keepalive-in-t) .